# TF Lite Android: No default_toolchain found for cpu 'arm64-v8a'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build TF Lite Android example app following this [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android/app/README.md).

- System – macOS High Siera 10.13.6
- gcc version 4.2.1

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: No default_toolchain found for cpu 'arm64-v8a'. Valid cpus are: [
  darwin,
  darwin_x86_64,
  k8,
  ios_x86_64,
  ios_i386,
  ios_armv7,
  ios_arm64,
  watchos_i386,
  watchos_armv7k,
  tvos_x86_64,
  tvos_arm64,
  armeabi-v7a,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to bazel not supporting arm64, this is supported here is a [workaround](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20192#issuecomment-404971539), the other way will be to just drop arm64-v8a from compilation flags.